# out-of-range value in sql server 2012 datetime comparision

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have this query in sql server 2012:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN count(*) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM Table1
WHERE ('20131104 00:00:00' > end_date OR '20141104 29:59:59' < start_date)
```

`Table1` `end_date` and `start_date` are both datetime, not null
I don't understand why i'm getting the error: "*The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*" if i'm using the standard varchar datetime format (or it is not?). If i remove the time part of the date the query works fine.

Comment: Have you tried '20131104 00:00:00.000' ?

Comment: Yes, i try that too with the same error message.

Comment: Miss typing error in the main problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
29:59:59
```

Should probably be 23, no?

Comment: What, you don't have 30-hour days?

Comment: I wish I had 30-hour days.  Nice catch Colm Prunty

Comment: daaamn fail!!!!! sorry guys for the loss time! the 29 was the problem :/

Comment: Stop using Martian time.

Answer (score 2):

A safe format for all versions of SQL Server would be `YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss`, so would be:

```
 WHERE ('2013-11-04T00:00:00' > end_date OR '2014-11-04T23:59:59' < start_date)
```

(And 29 should be 23, as Colm points out).

I also don't think this query is quite correct - 2014-11-04T23:59:59 will omit anything that has a milliseconds value during the last minute, such as 2014-11-04T23:59:59.537. I'd usually recommend with datetime to treat it as continuous, and thus switch to a semi-open interval - but I can't reconcile that with your current comparisons. One expected one could be:

```
 WHERE ('2013-11-04T00:00:00' >= end_date OR '2014-11-05T00:00:00' < start_date)
```

and now that both are just dates at midnight, they could be:

```
 WHERE ('20131104' >= end_date OR '20141105' < start_date)
```

(Noting, in both cases, that I've switched the `end_date` comparison to be `>=`).

Comment: I think that `WHERE ('20131104' > end_date OR '20141105' <= start_date)` is more appropriate.

Comment: @ypercube - I'm just not sure given that both of the current comparisons exclude equality. If both of them or one of them had already used equality, it would have made more sense and probably be easier to get to the correct actual query.